# Adding onto an array in Excel/Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Let's say I have a 2x2 array in Excel/Google Sheets:

```
={1,2;3,4}
```

To add on additional rows to this array -- for example, to make it 4x2, I can use `;`:

[image]

However, how could additional columns be added on, for example, to make the array 2x4, something like:

[image]

Comment: Mind you, this won't work in Excel

Comment: @JvdV how could that be done in Excel? Or it's not possible to combine a range with an array literal?

Comment: It won't be pretty, but if you want to output it like you have, one way is `=CHOOSE({1;2;3;4},B5:B6,C5:C6,{5,7},{6,8})`

Comment: @JvdV -- neat. How does `{1;2;3;4}` work as the index_num though?

Comment: Because I assumed you have access to dynamic-arrays using Excel 365, we can feed `CHOOSE()` an array. In this case a horizontal array, and it will return us all 4 parameters behind it which are vertical arrays. I hope that is clear =). But I think you can just stick to GoogleSheets if you want a user-friendly approach like you have =)

Comment: @JvdV I'd say post an answer, as your answer is pretty neat for excel!

Comment: If you want to add it to yours that would be completely fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Google Sheets you can use the following 2 formulas

```
=SEQUENCE(4,2)
```

```
={SEQUENCE(2,2),SEQUENCE(2,2,5)}
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`SEQUENCE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244)

Answer (score 3):

Arrays allow nesting in Google Sheets so you can try something like:

```
={B5:C6, {5,6;7,8}}
```

[image]

Comment: A very valuable answer.